# How can I invoke the fallback method with sendTransaction?

Tags: truffle, delegatecall

I'm testing the delegatecall vulnerability. And I've created two contracts to do that.

WalletLibrary.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyWalletLibrary {
    uint private value = 0;

    function setValue(uint a) public {
        value = a;
    }

    function getValue() public view returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And MyWallet.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyWallet {
    uint private value = 0;
    address private walletLibrary;

    constructor(address a) {
        walletLibrary = a;
    }

    fallback () external payable {
        (bool success, ) = walletLibrary.delegatecall(msg.data);
        if (! success) revert();
    }
}
```

Now I want to invoke MyWalletLibrary.setValue via the fallback function in MyWallet. So I created a truffle unit test file:

```
let MyWallet = artifacts.require("MyWallet")

it('delegate-test', async () => {
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    let MyWalletDeployed = await MyWallet.deployed()

    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[0],
        to:   MyWalletDeployed.address,
        data: '123'
    });
})
```

According to the document I should use sendTransaction(), but this sendTransaction() does not specify the method to call, aka "setValue".

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should be the function signature and the argument that you pass into it.

This is how you would do that in Solidity: `walletLibrary.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked("setValue(uint256)", "123"))`

For web3 you will want to use this [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall).

```
const myData = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'setValue',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: 'a'
    }]
}, ['123']);

web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[0],
        to:   MyWalletDeployed.address,
        data: myData
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added a value check on `a` and verified this works!